# Log file weighs hundreds of GB, and impossible to delete

Tags: windows, apache

That's probably the weirdest problem I've ever had.
I program using PhpStorm.

Suddenly there's an alert from Windows about low disk space.
After a quick research, turns out that my project's log file (where all the errors are logged) weighs 134 GB.

So the first question is - why did that happen?
When I try to delete it using the Windows file explorer, it says "You need permission to perform this action".

I've tried to delete it using the command prompt on administrator mode, it says "Access is denied".

That leads me to my second, and more important question - how do I fix that?
I've scanned the computer for viruses, found nothing.

[image: CMD response]

[image: Windows files explorer response]

Some technical details:
I use Windows 10 64bit, Apache 2.4, PHP 7.2.8.

Comment: 1) *"So the first question is - why did that happen?"* It's your application that generated it .. and we have no idea what your app does, what is written into that log etc. So that's the wrong question to ask here. So far this does not seem to be related to PhpStorm itself (not app fault) as it does not generate such logs; especially in user project folder.

Comment: 2) *"I've tried to delete it using the command prompt on administrator mode, it says "Access is denied""* Quite possibly that file is still opened (and therefore locked) by the process that writes there. So .. close all your apps and try again. If nothing -- shutdown Apache (as it might be generated by your web app) and other services; restarting OS may also help. If still nothing and it still grows -- use something like Process Monitor (free GUI tool) and see what processes are accessing that file. May need to check and adjust file permissions as well (but I doubt this will be needed).

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for the quick response. I managed to solve it.. Still not sure why it happened.

Comment: Quite likely (as for me) it was the way how you specified the path to that log .. so Apache have created it in the project root. But why it is so big .... no clues. Maybe you were doing ModRewrite debugging (when setup verbose output to see how it handles all steps of URL matching/rewriting?..)

Comment: It's not in the project root, it's in a tmp folder. And still didn't figure out why it happened.. i have no clue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it.

1. Created a new .log file, named 'temporary.log'
2. Stopped the apache service
3. Opened the httpd.conf file
4. Located the relevant virtual host.
5. Changed the ErrorLog file to 'temporary.log'
6. Started the apache service.
7. The problematic file disappeared.
8. Stopped the apache service again.
9. Changed the name of 'temporary.log' to the original .log file name.
10. Changed the ErrorLog file to the original file name.
11. Started the apache service again.

Comment: If it's an Apache log file (set in e.g. `ErrorLog`) all need to do is to stop Apache and the lock will be released.